# mySQL workbench Unable to access Performace Schema (sys)

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a problem on mySQL workbench (ubuntu 20.04). Apparently I get a message saying that is unable to access Performance Schema helper (sys). Can't open file '/etc/debian_version'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHNnM.png)

I have tried this:
cat /etc/debian_version
bullseye/sid
I have also tried:

```
mysql> select * from user where user='root'\G;
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR: 
No query specified
mysql> create user root@'localhost' identified by 'root';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
mysql> grant all on *.* to root;
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

Then I have changed the 'localhost' with '%' for the above commands it took me somewhere but no a positive result.

Not sure if these methods are related to my problem but please help me.
I have tried for hours to figure out what is wrong but can't manage it.

Comment: *ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected* Execute `USE sys` - what is the result?

Comment: 'mysql> USE sys'
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

Comment: Well, `sys` exists and is accessible. Now try to select from some table in `sys`, and finally to select from `performance_schema` again. Also test `USE performance_schema` and, if successful, select from its table(s).. PS. Anycase - edit MySQL's INI file and specify default database in client section.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Would you assist me with these as I'm new with in databases. 'mysql> SELECT * FROM sys.version;' 
| 2.1.1       | 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec) ' mysql> USE performance_schema' 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

Comment: If so then your problem is in the absence of `database` setting in option file or client command line / connector settings. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html and around.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: `sys` and `performance_schema` are the _last_ thing that a novice should study.  `CREATE DATABASE ...` for a new database of your choosing; `USE ...` it; `CREATE TABLE...`; play around.